# Type of children when passing multiple children

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm using NextJs with Typescript for my project.
While passing single children we can specify in pageProps that it is of type ReactNode, when passing multiple children we get array of ReactNodes. But it is giving me error when using type ReactNode or ReactFragment(which is I'm passing in this case). What should be correct type?

```
const PageContent: React.FC<PageContentProps> = ({ children }) => {
  return (                                         ^Error here
    <Flex>
      <Flex>
        {/* LHS */}
        <Flex>
          {children && children[0 as keyof typeof children]}
        </Flex>

        {/* RHS */}
        <Flex>
          {children && children[1 as keyof typeof children]}
        </Flex>
      </Flex>
    </Flex>
  );
};
```

I would also like to add the console log of 1 of children

```
$$typeof
: 
Symbol(react.element)
key
: 
null
props
: 
{children: {…}}
ref
: 
null
type
: 
Symbol(react.fragment)
_owner
: 
FiberNode {tag: 0, key: null, stateNode: null, elementType: ƒ, type: ƒ, …}
_store
: 
{validated: true}
_self
: 
undefined
_source
: 
undefined
```

I tried this and many other approaches but it's giving error

```
type PageContentProps = {
  children: Array<ReactFragment>;
};
```

Comment: Use the children API https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren

Comment: I'm making this component as Layout for different sections. Children API is discouraged in docs and they suggest to extract component instead which defeats the purpose of my approach also does not solves my question of type issue